# View problem when attaching workflow to list programmatically

Tags: list, workflow, list-view

Very irritating problem.  I have a list with the following view

```
<View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,All_Documents;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="True" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Url="Forms/AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Description"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
```

In the schema I set it so only the Description field should be displayed on the edit/new forms.  Everything works as expected until I programmatically attach a workflow to the list.  When I do this the new/edit forms stop displaying the description field and instead show the filename field.  I am lost as to why this is happening....any help?

Comment: Hi MikeC, I want to reproduce this if you haven't already fixed it. Could you post the code to attach the workflow and your schema. On the face nothing else looks wrong.

Comment: When attaching a workflow to a list, Sharepoint will add another column to the view which will be the workflow's name. This is to make it easy to jump to the workflow for the selected list item. I know that's not the answer, but just an explanation as to what is happening

Answer (score 1):

probably you can fix this by resetting fields visibility after adding WF, then hide all except description again; that might be columns indices change issue